# How to enter hours on X-axis in lineplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, seaborn

How to enter hours (HH:mm:ss.f) on the X-axis of a seaborn plot instead of numbers. Each time i try to make a plot, it automatically gets numbers, while i would show specific hours.

I have this kind of dataframe:

```
DF = pd.read_csv(r'CH:\Users\3Yellow_S1.csv', delimiter=';')

Hour              Acceleration
07:05:02.1        0.0212
07:05:02.2        0.0863
07:05:02.3        0.1568
07:05:02.4        0.2351
07:05:02.5        0.0123
```

This is my code to create a seaborn line plot:

```py
DF['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Hour']).dt.time # to be sure time format is correct

sns.lineplot(data=DF)
```

And this is what I obtain:

[image]

Instead of 20000, 40000, ... I would like to have hours.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `sns.lineplot(data=DF, x='Hour', y='Acceleration')`?

Comment: Yes, i get 'TypeError: Invalid object type at position 0'

Comment: `DF['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Hour'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f')` instead of `pd.to_datetime(DF['Hour']).dt.time` should work. (Together with `sns.lineplot(data=DF, x='Hour', y='Acceleration')`)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

# Dummy data I made using your output
data = {"Hour": ["07:05:02.1", "07:05:02.2", "07:05:02.3", "07:05:02.4", "07:05:02.5"],
        "Acceleration": [0.0212, 0.0863, 0.1568, 0.2351, 0.0123]}
DF = pd.DataFrame(data)
DF["Hour"] = pd.to_datetime(DF["Hour"], format="%H:%M:%S.%f")
sns.lineplot(x="Hour", y="Acceleration", data=DF)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S.%f")) # to include all the information you wanted (otherwise in default it doesnt include %H when plotting)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()  # to prevent clipping of labels

plt.show()
```

[image]